# undefined local variable or method `root_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have the following block of code in my rspec file located in the root of the /spec folder.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "home" do

 subject { page }

 before(:each) { visit root_path }

 describe "page" do
 it { should have_title('My Page')}
 end

end
```

When I run it I get

```
undefined local variable or method `root_path'
```

Which doesn't make any sense. When I followed the rails tutorial a similar set up worked just fine. Can anyone help?

**EDIT:**

My routes includes

```
root "static#home"
```

**EDIT 2:**

Reopening this topic. Moving my root declaration to the top did not fix it.

**EDIT 3:**

What worked was including url_helpers in my rspec config. I've never had to do this before. can anyone answer why this worked?

Comment: @emaillenin See edit I just made.

Comment: require `rails_helper` instead of `spec_helper` did it for me

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Named routes are not available in specs by default. Add the following code to `spec_helper.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Comment: This is something you should ask from rspec-rails developers. This line is not in the template that is generated on `rails generate rspec:install`: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/generators/rspec/install/templates/spec/spec_helper.rb.tt

Comment: In case of Engine, you need to change that to `AppName::Engine.routes.url_helpers`

Answer (score 17):

In your routes.rb, see if you have defined `root`. Something like this:

```
root :to => 'home#index'
```

Answer (score 10):

You figured out your issue, though I want to let others know that another reason they may get the error message...

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `root_path'
```

...is because they [renamed the "root" route](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

For example:

```
root to: 'pages#landing', as: :home
```

This will create `home_path` and `home_url` as named helpers in your application, whereas `root_path` and `root_url` will be **undefined**.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by `@emaillenin`, you'll need to include `root to: "controller#action"` in your `routes.rb` file

However, you need to ensure this is declared correctly - I've had it before that `root_path` is not found, only because it's at the end of the `routes.rb` file or something

It would be beneficial to show your entire `routes.rb` file