# My bootstrap navbar brand not linking back to home page

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't connect back to my home page when clicking the bootstrap brand. How can I get it to link back to home page (see `a class="navbar-brand"`)? Below is my code and I don't see anything wrong, much appreciated.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">

      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">

          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

 <a class="navbar-brand" href= "#">Biru29 今晚啤酒</a>

  </div>



  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><%= link_to "精選啤酒", birus_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "啤酒紀錄片", birumentary_path %></li> 
    </ul>


    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><%= link_to "詢購單+", orders_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "暫停會員", pause_path %></li> 
      <li><%= link_to "取消會員", cancel_path %></li> 
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div><!-- /.container --> 
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah need to insert the path inside the **href="homepage.html"** for the brand:

`<a class="navbar-brand" href= "#">Biru29 今晚啤酒</a>`

just like you're other pagelinks inside the menu  `<li><%= link_to "詢購單+", orders_path %></li>`.

Comment: How can I insert the path like such as order_page, because home_path or root_path doesn't seem to work? Thank you

Comment: Is the route configured for root_path? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741975/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your # tag is not linking any where try to link it to a section in your website with the id of that same section

Comment: This is a two year old question with an accepted answer. I don't Think Another answer will help here. 
Please don't practice necromancy.

Comment: lol sorry my bad bro lol only saw the date after i commented  thanks for the new word though