# Errors when using "paperclip"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I use gem "paperclip" and I can not figure out how to use it correctly. All the time there are some errors.

> [ab5aaf0e-3255-49d7-bc59-233aced581f3] NoMethodError (undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass):
>
> [ab5aaf0e-3255-49d7-bc59-233aced581f3] app/models/photo.rb:11:in
>   'as_json'
>
> [ab5aaf0e-3255-49d7-bc59-233aced581f3] app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:8:in `index'

What have I done wrong?

controller:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @photos = Photo.all

    render json: @photos
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.permit(
      :users_id, 
      :photo
    )
  end

end
```

model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "users_id"

  has_attached_file :photo, styles: {default: "150x150>"}, default_url: "/images/empty_photo.png", preserve_files: false
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

  def as_json(options={})
    super(options).merge({users_id: users_id,
                          photo: {
                            default_url: ENV['root_url'] + photo.url(:default),
                              original_url: ENV['root_url']+photo.url,
                          },
                        })
  end

  def image_from_url(url)
    self.photo = URI.parse(url)
  end


  def reprocess_image
    photo.reprocess!
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because `ENV['root_url']` returns `nil`.

Try to replace `ENV['root_url']` 
with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.root_url`

Comment: Either I misunderstood what to do, or it does not work at all

Comment: @user10254427 are you still getting same exception or message is changed?

Comment: Changed to: `undefined method root_url for #<Module:0x00007fc7b448c2d0> Did you mean? roles_url`

Comment: In your `routes.rb` you need to define the `root`, check this related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742007/5746504

Answer (score 0):

The error says that either `ENV['root_url']` or `photo.url(:default)` are nil. And I suppose it's the ENV variable.

Personally I would use a view to generate the json response and not the `as_json` method, since models does not have access to the current request, but views does so you can do something like `URI(request.url)+photo.url(:default)`

```
#views/photos/index.json.jbuilder (I use Jbuilder for json templates)
json.array! @photos do |photo|
  json.l_users_id photo.l_users_id
  json.photo do
    json.default_url URI(request.url)+photo.photo.url(:default)
    json.original_url URI(request.url)+photo.photo.url
  end
end
```